# VSTS (VSO) Powershell Module 1.0.1 Support

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

Does anyone know if the hosted agents in VSTS will be upgraded to Azure Powershell 1.0.1 from 0.9.8.1?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this website to see if there is any information related to Azure PowerShell 1.0.1: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/news-overview-vs

Answer (score 1):

Its beeing worked on right now and should be there in 2-3 weeks with the next VM Image update.

Comment: According to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/aa6293b7-bbf3-4f97-89f0-a56922fe4e4c/any-way-of-changing-version-of-azure-powershell-used-doing-a-release-using-an-azure-resource-group?forum=TFService a user reports that it has been updated.